# How to find type of properties on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

I want to find type of every properties on AgensGraph?

```
agens=# create (:v1{key:1,value:2});
GRAPH WRITE (INSERT VERTEX 1, INSERT EDGE 0)
```

How can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

Use function "jsonb_typeof" for finding type of properties.

```
agens=# match (n:v1) return jsonb_typeof(n.integer), jsonb_typeof(n.text);
 jsonb_typeof | jsonb_typeof 
--------------+--------------
 "number"     | "string"
(1 row)
```